# How to change the CheckBox rectangle size

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, checkbox

I am Working With ASP VB.net in that I have A checkBox ,I want to change the Size Of that checkbox I added css to change  but its not working the outer portion only get changing the rectangle remains same . can somebody help me ?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkDate" width="83pt"  runat="server" Height="20px" 
                   style="text-align: right; font-size:small" 
                   BorderStyle="None" autosize="false" size="250px" EnableViewState="False" />
```

Comment: you cant change the height, width or looks of any checkbox through css only.

Comment: Is there any other possibility to bring checkbox like input type checkbox like that .. I tried  that too but its not working

Comment: Another way is create custom checkbox that allow you to customize it as your needs. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27414/Customize-CheckBox-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
  .BigCheckBox input {width:20px; height:20px;}
</style>
```

In asp.net,

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CssClass="BigCheckBox" />
```